# How can I run a single only once request for with Locust (Python)

Tags: locust

There's a notion of `SetUp Thread Group` with `Number of Threads (users)` possibility on `JMeter` but when using `Locust`, the `on_start()` method is running as the same amount of users.

My workaround.

```py
@events.test_start.add_listener
def _(environment, **kwargs):
    global token
    token = get_token(environment.host)
```

...

```py
def get_token():
   r = requests.post(host+'/url/token', headers={}, ...)
   return r.text
```

To be honest, I don't really like that workaround.

I only need to get a Token `once`. I can reuse that token and also, it's a really heavy call (because the amount of validations), so I don't want that call to be executed each time for each user.

Is there a possible way to create a `Only Once` request that handles this at the beginning of the test?

Any ideas

Edited: This is related to Locust library NOT JMeter.

Comment: This question is about Locust, NOT JMeter. This is not duplicating any other question.

Comment: I have voted to reopen. I think your ”workaround” is the correct solution though. What is it that you dont like about it?

Comment: Thanks @Cyberwiz using global variables because, I was thinking using the `environment` instead and add a new property. But I cannot use it with `@events.request.add_listener` for logging.

Comment: I think a global here is fine. If you prefer, you can add your own fields to the environment (available as self.environment in the User instance)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I think I will be adding the custom field to the environment and use `self.environment`  as you mention. Thanks again for your time @Cyberwiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your ”workaround” is the correct solution.

But if you for some reason really dont like module-scoped variables and the `global` keyword, you can add your own fields to the `environment` (available as `self.environment` in the User instance).

Comment: What was the solution here? Do you have a solution for on_stop as well? I'm looking for a function I call once for all users at the start and stop