# Executing the auth token once per run - Locust

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

Ideally I want to grab the token one time (1 request) and then pass that token into the other 2 requests as they execute.  When I run this code through Locust though...

```
from locust import HttpUser, constant, task
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


class ProcessRequests(HttpUser):

    host = 'https://hostURL'
    wait_time = constant(1)

    def on_start(self):

        tenant_id = "tenant123"
        client_id = "client123"
        secret = "secret123"
        scope = "api://123/.default"

        body ="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + client_id + "&client_secret=" + secret + "&scope=" + scope

        tokenResponse = self.client.post(
                f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token",
                body,
                headers = { "ContentType": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} 
            )

        response = tokenResponse.json()
        responseToken = response['access_token']
        

        self.headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + responseToken}


    @task
    def get_labware(self):
        self.client.get("/123", name="Labware",headers=self.headers)

    @task
    def get_instruments(self):
        self.client.get("/456", name="Instruments", headers=self.headers)
```

It ends up firing off multiple token requests that don't stop..

[image]

Any ideas how to fix this to make the token only run once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case it runs once **per user** so my expectation is that you spawned 24 users and the number of `Labware` and `Instruments` is at least 2x times higher so it seems to work exactly according to the [documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/writing-a-locustfile.html#on-start-and-on-stop-methods).

> Users (and [TaskSets](https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/tasksets.html#tasksets)) can declare an `on_start` method and/or `on_stop` method. A **User will call its on_start method when it starts running**, and its `on_stop` method when it stops running. For a TaskSet, the `on_start` method is called when a simulated user starts executing that TaskSet, and `on_stop` is called when the simulated user stops executing that TaskSet (when `interrupt()` is called, or the user is killed).

If you want to get the token only once and then share it across all the virtual users you can go for the [workaround from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69901539/how-can-i-run-a-single-only-once-request-for-with-locust-python)

```
@events.test_start.add_listener
def _(environment, **kwargs):
    global token
    token = get_token(environment.host)
```

and put into this `get_token()` function what you have in `on_start()` one.

More information: [Locust with Python: Introduction, Correlating Variables, and Basic Assertions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-python)

Comment: yep, you are exactly right.  I tested it again and it looks like that is what is happening.  This behavior is different than what I am seeing in K6 and JMeter, so I was confused.  Looks like it is working as expected.  I will look into that workaround you mentioned